# SwiftUI : How to ignore NavigationView When Add ScrollView

Tags: swift, mobile, swiftui

My previous code is

```
VStack {
    MapView(coordinate: landmark.locationCoordinate)
        .frame(height: 300, alignment: .center)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    CircleImageView(image: landmark.image)
    
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("\(landmark.name)")
            .font(.title)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        
        HStack {
            Text("\(landmark.park)")
            Spacer()
            Text("\(landmark.state)")
        }
        .font(.subheadline)
        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        
        
        Divider()
        Text("\(landmark.category)")
            .font(.title2)
        Text("\(landmark.description)")
        
    }
    .padding()

    Spacer()
}
```

My current build works fine. But when I add `ScrollView` as parent of my code, the map does not ignore the safe area.

| Current build | After adding `ScrollView` |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Current build] | [image: Map stops at safe area] |

I used `edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` but it didn't work. By the way, I am new to SwiftUI so I will appreciate any help.

Comment: `ScrollView{...} .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` should work

Comment: Here's a video I did explaining how to work with the safe area: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0NDKxvfg40

Comment: thanks, @achu for helping me it works